# Very fast in-memory SQL server

Tags: sql

I have an ETL problem that's small enough to live in memory but complex enough to be managed by a team of SQL devs. What's the best way to get very fast standard-compliant SQL where concurrency isn't needed? SQLite is out, as Full Outer Join is absent and we use it. I haven't been having good luck with Ignite so far, as SQL in it really isn't that fast.

Comment: Note that you can [simulate FULL JOIN with SQLite](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1923259/2557263) with some modifications. Otherwise, it fills every other criteria.

Comment: [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org/)  and [H2](http://h2database.com/) come to mind

Comment: I'm basically landing with a local spark process at this point. It seems to work well, despite lack of indexes.